# Get client certificate information on Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, ssl

My Android application needs to get information (common name, validity) about the client certificate used for a TLS connection. I thought that I could use the method getCertificateChain() from the KeyChain class (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain) with the correct alias, but I was only able to find the CA certificates, not the client certificate itself. And I must say I'm a bit lost inside all these KeyStore, X509KeyManager and SocketFactory!
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using mutual SSL? Otherwise there is no client certificate in TLS except the root CAs the client is validating against.

Comment: Thanks @Izruo, yes it was about mutual authentication, I should have add this kind of 'details'. But the information I need is indeed returned by getCertificateChain() (the debug I implemented first was pretty bad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, the information is indeed returned in the first item of the array returned by getCertificateChain().